# Custom group by query

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

I have a table containing three columns: **EmployeeID**, **Department**, **Location**

Each employee potentially  can have **multiple** departments and can be located in **more than one** locations.

By SQL query on any RDBMS,
I need return the distinct set of Departments(separated by hyphen), the distinct set of Locations(separated by hyphen) against each EmployeeID.

For the following record in DB,

1. EMP1, HR, Kolkata
2. EMP1, HR, Delhi
3. EMP1, Facility, Mumbai
4. EMP1, Facility, Kolkata

I need to get the following result :  EMP1, HR-Facility, Kolkata-Delhi-Mumbai

Any help will be more than welcome.

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your question appropriately.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, The query must be ANSI-SQL to be run in any RDBMS

Comment: I don't think this is possible because there is no in-row aggregating function defined in the ANSI SQL standard. Normally you would achieve this using either SQL server's STUFF or Oracle's LISTAGG. If it has to remain generic you may be better off writing code (C#, java etc) to do the aggregating.

Comment: @booyaa Well, you could do it with subqueries... if there was `sum` over varchars, which there isn't. Shame :) Perhaps you could create a user defined function that would be different for the different database engines? In any case, coding against ANSI-SQL and expecting it to run (and run well!) on any RDBMS is naïve. It still doesn't quite work that way.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with ANSI_SQL either. You'll need a database sepcific method to solve this issue, or an PL/SQL block

Comment: @labbhattacharjee . . . That is simply not true.  If you have more than one dbms in mind, then there is overlapping syntax -- but some things simply cannot be done.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I can think of doing this in ANSI SQL is using `dense_rank()` and conditional aggregation.  Assuming there are no more than three values for each group:

```
select empid,
       trim(trailing '-' from
            concat( max(case when l_seqnum = 1 then concat(location, '-') else '' end),
                    max(case when l_seqnum = 2 then concat(location, '-') else '' end),
                    max(case when l_seqnum = 3 then concat(location, '-') else '' end)
           ) as locations,
       trim(trailing '-' from
            concat( max(case when d_seqnum = 1 then concat(department, '-') else '' end),
                    max(case when d_seqnum = 2 then concat(department, '-') else '' end),
                    max(case when d_seqnum = 3 then concat(department, '-') else '' end)
           ) as departments
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by empid order by department) as d_seqnum,
             dense_rank() over (partition by empid order by location) as l_seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
group by empid;
```

However, most databases have more reasonable ways to express this.

Comment: Nicely done, although I had to pair the wrap the location and department concat calls in pairs [```CONCAT(CONCAT(A,B),C)```] in oracle to get it to work. And I think TRIM is an oracle call, only had SQL 2008 handy so maybe it got introduced in a later version.

Comment: @booyaa . . . No one, least of all Oracle, would suggest that they support ANSI SQL.  In Oracle, you would just use the concatenation operator (`||`), which is also supported by ANSI.  But there are better ways to write the query in Oracle.  As I say in the answer, this is ANSI SQL, but it is probably not the best way to express the query in any real database.